# Excel/VBA - Using different QuerySelectors in loop

Tags: xml, vba, web-scraping, queryselector

I have an issue where different websites require *different types of QuerySelector* (i.e. `GetElementsByClassName`, `GetElementsByTagName`, `querySelectorAll`, etc.) in the loop to be able to return a result.

As it stands, this code WORKS to retrieve the website information if I use a hard-coded FIX SELECTOR at the line of "Set list = html.querySelectorAll(ID)" but it DOESN'T WORK if I try to make it VARIABLE based on the sheet row attributed query.name in the loop.

I'm not sure if this is simply assigning the correct variable-type but I just don't know how to handle making this part work...

```
Sub FETCHER()
    Dim URL As String, tag As String, ID As String, LastRow As Integer, j As Long
    Dim html As HTMLDocument, list As Object, i As Long

    Dim xmlhttp As Object
    Set xmlhttp = CreateObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP.6.0")
    'CreateObject("WINHTTP.WinHTTPRequest.5.1")

    Worksheets("TEST").Activate
    LastRow = Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For j = 2 To LastRow
        With ActiveSheet
            URL = Range("S" & j).Text            'URL = https://stackoverflow.com/
            tag = Range("T" & j).Text            'TAG = getElementsByClassName '<--- Where I want to assign the selector type (i.e. getelementsbyclassname, getelementsbytagname, etc.)
            ID = Range("U" & j).Text             'Element ID = "CONTENT"
        End With

        Set xmlhttp = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
        Set html = New HTMLDocument

        With xmlhttp
            .Open "GET", URL, False
            .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Chrome/39.0.2171.95"
            .Send

            html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
        End With

        'Set list = html.querySelectorAll("CONTENT")   <---Example..
        Set list = html.querySelectorAll(ID)          '<---This WORKS as it's HARD-CODED
        Set list = html.TAG(ID)                       '<---This DOESN'T WORK in trying to make it VARIABLE

        For i = 0 To 5
            With ActiveSheet
                .Cells(j, 22 + i) = list.Item(i).innerText
                '.Cells(j + 1, 22 + 1) = list.Item(i).getAttribute("href")
            End With
        Next
    Next
End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Needs some examples of what's in your S, T, U column cells.  You cannot do this `html.TAG(ID)` but without knowing what's in TAG it's difficult to make suggestions.

Comment: Hey, I've updated the post by adding an example of what one (i) row would look like  in the loop. TAG represents the "HTML DOM querySelector()"

Answer (score 2):

I think you are trying to invoke a method by string variable in which case you need CallByName e.g.

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Dim xmlhttp  As MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Dim html As MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    Set xmlhttp = New MSXML2.XMLHTTP60
    Set html = New MSHTML.HTMLDocument

    With xmlhttp
        .Open "GET", "https://stackoverflow.com/", False
        .setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Chrome/39.0.2171.95"
        .send
        html.body.innerHTML = .responseText
    End With

    Dim tag As String, list As Object

    tag = "GetElementsByTagName"
    Set list = CallByName(html, tag, VbMethod, "a") '<==note the args at end e.g. here the element type selector of "a" for a tag elements.
    Debug.Print list.Length
End Sub
```

You can't use `object.[string variable for method]`

Comment: I think you're on the right track :) That said, how would you write it since I can't declare solely "html" and putting "html." throws an error...?

Comment: Updated for you. Give that a go.

Comment: I've played around with the updated formula and it keeps crashing excel/vba (i.e. not responding)... The only work around I have is an IF/ELSE IF statement and then it runs the appropriate "set list"..

Comment: Please pastebin.com a link to the entire code which is causing the crash. My code above runs just fine.

Comment: Hi, do you want to pastebin the link?

Comment: I couldn't generate a report as the file would first "not respond" and then crash. That said, I upVoted your solution as it was way more than enough to have a functional query. Thanks for your time; I really appreciate it :)

Comment: You are welcome. If you can find an actual url example that replicates the problem I will have a look.

Comment: @QHarr does this trick of using CallByName working with css selector?!

Comment: you mean to call "querySelector" ? Have you tried it?